# Error when multiplying label value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to multiply a label value and i get an "Input string was not in a correct format."

Below is my code

```
            double q = Convert.ToDouble(Label30.Text);
            double b = 0.2 * a;
            Label44.Text = Convert.ToString(b);

            double c = Convert.ToDouble(Label35.Text);
            double d = 0.15 * c;
            Label32.Text = Convert.ToString(d);

            double e = Convert.ToDouble(Label39.Text);
            double f = 0.15 * e;
            Label40.Text = Convert.ToString(f);
```

It points out the error from the variable "c"

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: and what help are you hoping to get without specifying the values of `Label35.Text`?

Comment: Very meaningful naming convention.

Comment: I meant the value, not the type.

Comment: Try the debugger and see what's happening. I bet on a wrong string which does not represent a double.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `System.FormatException` try to use

```
double c = double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```